# Jmeter _ Input file path setup in batch file

Tags: jmeter

I tried to set input file path as below. But getting error as

```
"WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.".
```

Can some one help me.

This is how I've configured:

```
cd D:\Automation\Jmeter_Param\apache-jmeter-4.0\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin\
```

set my_dataset=`D:\Automation\Jmeter_Param\apache-jmeter-4.0\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin\Deactivate.csv`

set my_txnset=`D:\Automation\Jmeter_Param\apache-jmeter-4.0\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin\Deactivate\credentials_prod.csv`

```
jmeter -n -t D:\Automation\Jmeter_Param\apache-jmeter-4.0\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin\Deactivate\Deactivate.jmx
```

Here my_dataset and my_txnset has been called out under Global and used.

Comment: To resolve this issue, run jmeter.bat as Administrator once. After that jmeter can be opened as normal user without this message. [Reference](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/156801). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter release notes](https://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html):

> Note that under some windows systems you may have this WARNING:
>
> ```
> java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences
> WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0
> x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(…) returned error code 5.
> ```
>
> The fix is to run JMeter as Administrator, it will create the registry key for you, then you can restart JMeter as a normal user and you won't have the warning anymore.

So just [run the command prompt as Administrator](https://www.howtogeek.com/194041/how-to-open-the-command-prompt-as-administrator-in-windows-8.1/) once and issue will go away.

Also be aware that according to [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article you should always be using the latest version of JMeter so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.2.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-2-1-released-td5728641.html) (or whatever is the latest stable version available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page) on next available opportunity